# Recording app for Android

Tags: java, android, audio-recording, microphone

Basically, I am trying to make an app able to record something using the mic and save what was recorded in a file. I have followed a tutorial I found and so far, I have this code:

```
package com.nicu.bogdan.vrec;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Button record;
Button stop;
Button play;
static String audioFilePath;
boolean isRecording;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    record = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);

    if (!hasMicrophone())
    {
        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(false);
        record.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        play.setEnabled(false);
        stop.setEnabled(false);
    }



}

public boolean hasMicrophone() {
    PackageManager pmanager = this.getPackageManager();
    return pmanager.hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE);
}

public void record (View view) throws IOException
{

    audioFilePath =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/"
            + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ".3gp";
    isRecording = true;
    stop.setEnabled(true);
    play.setEnabled(false);
    record.setEnabled(false);


        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); //the error comes from this line
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFilePath);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();


    mediaRecorder.start();
}

public void stop (View view)
{

    stop.setEnabled(false);
    play.setEnabled(true);
    if (isRecording)
    {
        record.setEnabled(false);
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        mediaRecorder = null;
        isRecording = false;
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
        record.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

public void play (View view) throws IOException
{
    play.setEnabled(false);
    record.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(true);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFilePath);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nicu.bogdan.vrec" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The layout is pretty simple, 3 buttons: record, stop and play. I'm not going to post that code since it's not important.

After I click the "record" button, I get this error: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.` from the line I have commented above. Now the thing is that I get this only when I run the app from my Nexus 5, when I run the app from Genymotion emulator, I don't get this error.

Comment: Try to replace `AudioSource.MIC` with `AudioSource.DEFAULT`.

Comment: @Titus I get the same error message.

Comment: You can try some of the other `AudioSource`s, you can find a list of them [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html) or you can try to use [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) instead of `MediaRecorder`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

to your manifest because accessing the audio source is modifying the audio settings.

Comment: @Lerul I think it would be interesting if this answer solved your problem?